# how to convert a BigInteger into a string of ascii

Tags: java, encryption, integer, rsa

Was looking for some help on transforming a large on how to convert am large integer value into a a string of ascii characters;

After doing some work with RSA encryption/decryption i decrypted this **140472961968666030223** to be the message now i need to convert this into a sting of ascii characters. I have found this method for converting a string of ascii characters into a large integer, but I can not for the life of me figure out how to reverse the method.

> Note: For a block with 8 characters,the resulting integer can also be calculated by:
>
> R= c<sub>7</sub> * 256<sup>7</sup> + c<sub>6</sub> * 256<sup>6</sup> +    c<sub>5</sub> * 256<sup>5</sup> + c<sub>4</sub> * 256<sup>4</sup> + c<sub>3</sub> * 256<sup>3</sup> + c<sub>2</sub> * 256<sup>2</sup> + c<sub>1</sub> * 256 + c<sub>0</sub> * 1

so i can see how if you knew that characters or something it would be easy to undo, but in this case all i have is that BigInteger, how am i supposed to know what to take out (like what blocks) and where they go?)

If anyone has a better method please shoot because this one isnt looking to promising!

thanks!

Comment: The result of encryption is usually a `byte[]`, not a `BigInteger`. Are you rolling your own encryption code? That's almost always a bad idea.

Comment: well i was Given a Big Integer as the cipher text so after deciphering using rsa which is something like Code^Private key mod n ;; and yeah that gave me another integer

Comment: So the fact the byte[] was encrypted is not important, you just want to know how to turn a byte[] into a BigInteger and the constructor which does this doesn't work for you?

Comment: When using RSA, you need you use a proper padding scheme. PKCS #1 defines such schemes (in particular OAEP), and it also defines how to convert between bytes and bigintegers. And you shouldn't use normal BigInteger classes for private key operations. That opens up huge side-channels, allowing an attacker who can measure how long your decryption takes to recover your private key.

Answer (score 0):

If `R` is a BigInteger you can recover the `c` array as follows:

```
byte [] c = new byte[8];
for (int i=0; i<c.length; i++) {
    c[i] = R.byteValue();
    R = R.shiftRight(8);
}
```